# Why does the compiler prefer f(const void*) to f(const std::string &)?

Tags: c++, stdstring, string-literals, overloading, overload-resolution

Consider the following piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// void f(const char *) { std::cout << "const char *"; } // <-- comment on purpose
void f(const std::string &) { std::cout << "const std::string &"; }
void f(const void *) { std::cout << "const void *"; }

int main()
{
    f("hello");
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

I compiled this program using `g++ (Ubuntu 6.5.0-1ubuntu1~16.04) 6.5.0 20181026`:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 strings_1.cpp -Wall
$ ./a.out

const void *
```

Note that the comment is there on purpose to test, otherwise the compiler uses `f(const char *)`.

So, why does the compiler pick `f(const void*)` over `f(const std::string &)`?

Comment: Here's the relevant part of the standard: http://eel.is/c++draft/over.ics.rank#2.1

Comment: @geza awesome. I was looking for it, thanks.

Comment: The overloading resolution rule here is simple and unchanged in the many C++ versions.

Comment: ```#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
int main() {
 std::cout << typeid("foo").name() << " - " << typeid(string("foo")).name();
 return 0;
}```

Comment: Well, a string literal is **not an `std::string`**, it's a static array of `char`s, which decays to a pointer to its first character. **This behavior is inherited from C** which never had something like `std::string`, but ample amounts of code handling strings nonetheless.

Comment: If you specifically want a `std::string` literal you can achieve that by adding a `s` behind the literal. This is a user-defined literal which is available since C++14. https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s

Comment: @geza Consider posting as an answer...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Converting to a `std::string` requires a "user defined conversion".

Converting to `void const*` does not.

User defined conversions are ordered behind built in ones.